# Holding Arrow Keys Down For Character Movement C# .Net ISSUES

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, keypress

So in short i'm simply trying to move a rectangle around a Canvas object in a WPF application. What i have here is my KeyDown event function. The problem is, when i hold a key down for long, it launches this function over and over again rapidly and screws up my rectangle location code.

My theory/logic behind it:
  BECAUSE WHEN YOU HOLD A BUTTON DOWN ON A KEYBOARD IT DOES NOT MOVE SMOOTHLY (TEST IT ON THE SCROLL BAR IN YOUR BROWSER, IT STARTS, pauses, THEN CONTINUES SMOOTHLY), i want it to start a forms timer that moves the object in the UI. Then when the KeyUp event happens, the timer STOPS.

```
public void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string msg;
    string keystr = e.Key.ToString();
    Key keyval = e.Key;


    switch (keystr)
    {
        case "Down":
            Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
            Display.Content = "Down";
            foreach (Character character in creatures)
            {
                //character.buttondown = true;
                character.Position("Down");
            }
            break;
        case "Up":
            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
            Display.Content = "Up";
            foreach (Character character in creatures)
            {
                //character.buttondown = true;
                character.Position("Up");
            }
            break;
        case "Left":
            Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
            Display.Content = "Left";
            foreach (Character character in creatures)
            {
                //character.buttondown = true;
                character.Position("Left");
            }
            break;
        case "Right":
            Display.Content = "Right";
            foreach (Character character in creatures)
            {

                //character.buttondown = true;
                character.Position("Right");
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Display.Content = "No key is pressed.";
    foreach (Character character in creatures)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            character.StopIt();
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            character.StopIt();
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            character.StopIt();
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            character.StopIt();
        }

    }
}
```

and just for reference if you need my *rectangle* class code i'll post what happens if the RIGHT arrow key is pressed:

1. Position is called

   ```
   public void Position(String Direction)
   {

       if (Direction == "Right")
       {
           tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
           tmr.Interval = this.waitTime;
           tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(GoRight);
           tmr.Start();
       }
    }
   ```
2. GoRight is called:

   ```
   public void GoRight(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       if (x < Background.ActualWidth - CharacterWidth)
       {
           if (goRight)
           {
               x += incrementSize;
               CharacterImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x);

           }
           if (x > Background.ActualWidth - CharacterWidth)
           {
               goRight = false;
               tmr.Stop();
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Finally, StopIt is called in the KeyUp event:

```
public void StopIt()
{
    tmr.Stop();
    goRight = true;
    goLeft = true;
    goUp = true;
    goDown = true;
}
```

I've only been learning c# for a couple months now so i'm trying to keep it relatively simple if possible, and only use .net.

Any help would be appreciated!!

EDIT:: **MY SOLUTION:**

I simply made a while(flag) loop around my switch case. Then i set flag = false within the cases. When Key UP is pressed i set flag equal to true again. YAY

Comment: Just as a note, I'd suggest you use something like XNA or OpenTK if you want to make a game. I solved a similar problem for a fighter using MonoGame's input and a specially built input queue. WPF is really made for UI.

Comment: @AlexBeisley of course, but for some simple games, it's OK (even some `GDI+` in `winforms` can do). There is some game even made from the controls like `DataGrid` or `DataGridView`, it's funny.

Comment: This is a project for my starter c# class. I dont really want to get into XNA unless i have to.

Comment: @RyanBrady the problem is, you're getting around it by learning WPF, which is equally complicated and has a different purpose. Full XNA is probably overkill and requires extra things to be installed, which is why I tend to prefer MonoGame: you can package the references with the project. Ultimately, the complexity is going to be just as bad, but at least it'll be more pertinent. Alternatively, you could look into WPF's Animations, transforms, etc, since they may help you if you stick to the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want your character to move on the initial KeyDown event. Then you want to ignore any subsequent KeyDown events until you get a KeyUp event.

So you can ignore the subsequent KeyDown events by checking e.IsRepeat e.g.

```
public void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsRepeat) return;

    // rest of your code...
```

BTW, the non-smooth movement that you observe when scrolling an application is caused by the keyboard repeat delay. You can set this in the keyboard properties or though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.keyboarddelay.aspx

Comment: Ah this is exactly what i wanted! Thank you! I fixed it with a while loop currently, but this will be so much better!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about WPF to tell you what is going on, though you may be correct about the push button/pause thing.  It depends on how WPF treats keypresses.  My guess would be that it does so the same way most Microsoft forms work; it has a pause to keep you from typing multiple characters at a time.  There may be a way around this but I'm not sure.

What I will say though is that you should use something designed for games.  When I first tried creating games I did so in a style similar to what you are doing and it doesn't work.  What you are using is designed for office software and will not give you access to what you need; at least not without fighting and workarounds.  As was suggested by Alex Beisley look into XNA.  It's a dead language unfortunately but it died fairly recently.  It uses c#, was made by Microsoft, and is powerful enough to do what you want without fighting you and easy enough to use once you get the hang of it.  It's a shame to see it killed off.

If you want to torture yourself then I'd suggest going the route I've been trying which is to learn C++ and DirectX.  It is not easy and you will need to be patient and go through multiple tutorials (no one tutorial seems to do a good job explaining anything).  DirectX and C++ are not going anywhere soon, so they are a safe bet if you are looking to get into a long term language.

Comment: I appreciate the tips, but i'm working on this for my C# class so its gotta be c#. Nothing to intricate, but i have to assume there has got to be some easy way to move a rectangle around a canvas using key input..

Comment: @RyanBrady: There are several easy ways, but the easiest of all would be to use a framework designed for your application. And those exist. You can do this in WPF, but you may not get much information on it because anyone doing this seriously would be using an OpenTK usercontrol in WPF or they'd skip WPF entirely.

Comment: @AlexBeisley Check out my edit! It was the simplest fix ever. All i really  needed to do was move a rectangle around, and now it works flawlessly. Looking at the amount of code i wrote to accomplish this, do you think it is over complicated compared to your method? Do you like the style i did it in straight .net?

Comment: @RyanBrady: That's a good solution, and congrats on not making it terribly long. I still stand by my comment that you are bending a complicated API to do something it wasn't made for, and that your whole program is just as complex as it would be using any other framework, so you might as well use a fitting one. Still, glad you succeeded.