# Removing the delay after KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, events, keypress, keydown

When I hold a key in my game to move my player:

```
public void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        Player.MoveUp();
    }
}
```

The player instantly moves one step as soon as I press the down arrow, and then pauses for a short duration before starting to smoothly move again. Why's this? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of character repeat delay in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172621/how-can-i-get-rid-of-character-repeat-delay-in-c)

Comment: I second that link. It's the right solution for moving player sprites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172621/how-can-i-get-rid-of-character-repeat-delay-in-c) is incorrect, unfortunately. It doesn't ignore repeated `KeyDown` events, and so will gradually increase the "delta" value in the direction being handled by each key case. It also doesn't respond to the keypress immediately (i.e. no action happens until the first timer tick).

This answer to [Holding Arrow Keys Down For Character Movement C# .Net ISSUES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19825344/3538012) explains how to ignore the subsequent `KeyDown` events, but doesn't explain how then your character would move.

In other words, I couldn't find a duplicate question that actually *correctly* answers your question. So…

The basic technique you want to do is:

1. Don't move on the actual key input. Instead, generate your own timing logic that will move the object.
2. Instead of using the `KeyDown` event to actually move the object, use it to set a movement direction, which is then processed by your timing logic.

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this. One version would look like this:

```
private bool _moveUp;
private bool _moveDown;
private bool _moveLeft;
private bool _moveRight;

// You can add the Timer in the Winforms Designer instead if you like;
// The Interval property can be configured there at the same time, along
// with the Tick event handler, simplifying the non-Designer code here.
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _movementTimer = new Timer { Interval = 100 };

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _movementTimer.Tick += movementTimer_Tick;
}

private void movementTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DoMovement();
}

private void _DoMovement()
{
    if (_moveLeft) Player.MoveLeft();
    if (_moveRight) Player.MoveRight();
    if (_moveUp) Player.MoveUp();
    if (_moveDown) Player.MoveDown();
}

// You could of course override the OnKeyDown() method instead,
// assuming the handler is in the Form subclass generating the
// the event.
public void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsRepeat)
    {
        // Ignore key repeats...let the timer handle that
        return;
    }

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys.Up:
        _moveUp = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Down:
        _moveDown = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Left:
        _moveLeft = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Right:
        _moveRight = true;
        break;
    }

    _DoMovement();
    _movementTimer.Start();
}

public void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys.Up:
        _moveUp = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Down:
        _moveDown = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Left:
        _moveLeft = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Right:
        _moveRight = false;
        break;
    }

    if (!(_moveUp || _moveDown || _moveLeft || _moveRight))
    {
        _movementTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Do note that the timer objects in .NET have limited resolution. I show an interval of 100 ms (10 times per second) above (same as in the other question's answer), and this is about as frequent an update as you're going to reliably get. Even then, the timer's `Tick` event may not (and probably won't) be raised on *exactly* 100 ms intervals. There will be some variation back and forth. But it will be close enough for a basic game.

If you need more precision than that, you will have to implement your own state-polling-and-animation loop somewhere. That's a whole other ball o' wax. :)

Comment: I don't have the attribute of "IsRepeat", so I had to make a separate function to determine if I'm already moving.

Answer (score 0):

A subjectivly elegent approach:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Timer timer;
    private static bool[] keys_down;
    private static Keys[] key_props;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keys_down = new bool[4];
        key_props = new []{Keys.A, Keys.D, Keys.W, Keys.S};
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 15; // Roughly 67 FPS
        timer.Tick += tick;
        timer.Start();
        KeyDown += key_down_event;
        KeyUp += key_up_event;
        ... // More things to do when the form loads.
    }

    private void tick(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... // Do this every timing interval.
        byte n = 0;
        foreach (var v in keys_down)
        {
            if (n == 3 && v)
                ... // If the "s" key is being held down, no key delay issues. :)
            n++;
        }
        ...
    }

    private void key_down_event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        byte n = 0;
        foreach (var v in keys_down)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == key_props[n])
                keys_down[n] = true;
            n++;
        }
    }

    private void key_up_event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        byte n = 0;
        foreach (var v in keys_down)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == key_props[n])
                keys_down[n] = false;
            n++;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solutions to create a small copy of Flappy Bird. Perhaps my decision will help someone. 
I used the addition of a player position with a variable in timer to simulate gravity. When I press W, I turned off the further reception of the command using bool and simply inverted gravity

```
private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bird.Location.Y >= 540)
        {
            bird.Location = new Point(bird.Location.X, 540);
        }
        else 
        {
            bird.Location = new Point(bird.Location.X, bird.Location.Y+grav);
        } 
    }

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W && press == false)
        {
            press = true;
            grav = -10;
        }
        return;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W && press == true)
        {
            press = false;
            grav = 5;
        }
        return;
    }
```