# Console check for pressed keys like in monogame

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

In my console application, I would like to be able to detect for key presses somewhat like in mono, where you can get a list of the currently pressed keys and check if a key is on the list, or detect if a key is being pressed. My problem with using

```
if( Console.KeyAvailable ) k = Console.ReadKey( true ).Key;
```

is the fact that there will be a delay after I press the first key. You can see an example of this if you open notepad and hold down "A". A will be pressed, then a delay, and then A will be spammed.

How can I get keyboard input without the delay in between presses? I'm not afraid to use low level functions such as hooking into kernel32.dll

Comment: have you tried a simple google search on the following `C# Listen for key press in .NET console app`

Comment: Yes, but most of the results that I get have to do with Console.ReadKey, which will do the "A", pause, and then spam "A" when I want it to just spam "A" as soon as you press it.

One result I did find was this, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/ but I'm not sure how I can run my code while that's going.

Comment: look here for an example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Comment: But this does the same thing as my question has specified - if you press "A", it will output A, then it will pause, and then it'll spam "A". This does the same thing with Console.KeyAvailable. If you hold "A", and have Console.Write output the result, it'll say "A", wait a moment, and then spam "A". Perhaps you're not quite getting my definition of "wait". I don't mean wait as in the application halts, I mean the Console.ReadKey doesn't pick up on the fact that A is being held. Open notepad and hold "A". You'll notice A printed once, then a pause, then it'll be spammed.

Comment: To the downvoters and commenters, he's saying that he doesn't want a delay after the first key press. It's like thus: - .... -------------. This is a valid question about the Console and the nature of ReadKey. @MethodMan, his code already does what "Listen for key press" suggests. Whether it's a tight loop or not does not negate the fact there's a delay, which is the Windows OS doing that. 

That being said, OP, Console does not support such a thing. You're going to need to get key down events from hooks. However, there are plenty of great libraries/Nuget packages for just that.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear, I wasn't quite sure how to put that into words. You could answer the question by giving an answer of some example Nuget libraries, as that would point me in the right direction. I really have to say thank you for putting what I was asking into words!

Comment: I'm in the middle of writing just that. I'm going to write some example code for you because there's a bit of nuance to the approach. The answer will be here in a couple of hours because it's lunch time.

Comment: So I wrote some code that intercepted the message loops, but ultimately the operating system is still what controls the delay. The message itself is delayed, so there's no way to simply repeat the message. The real approach here is to either implement a wonky timing system (which is many people's approach) or continue to fire an event for as long as a key is down until there's a key up event. I'm going to work on that later when I get home and get an answer to you, because there's little or very bad stuff about it on Stack Overflow. It might be worth its own post for Googlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wrote some code, based off what I've read so far.

**Step 1: Copy the following code into your console application. It must be STAThread or it will throw an error. Put in the commands you want to use in the switch statement. All other keys will be blocked by ReadKey(true).**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyListener.RegisterHotKey(Keys.A);
            KeyListener.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(KeyListener_HotKeyPressed);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

        static void KeyListener_HotKeyPressed(object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Keys.A:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do stuff");
                    return;
                }
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms. You need this to have a hidden Form that is necessary for the message loop for the keyboard hook.**

**Step 3: Add the following static class. It does all the heavy lifting of the keyboard hooks for you, so you don't have to do it.**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    public static class KeyListener
    {
        public static event EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs> HotKeyPressed;

        public static int RegisterHotKey(Keys key, KeyModifiers modifiers)
        {
            _windowReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            int id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _id);
            _wnd.Invoke(new RegisterHotKeyDelegate(RegisterHotKeyInternal), _hwnd, id, (uint)modifiers, (uint)key);
            return id;
        }

        public static int RegisterHotKey(Keys key)
        {
            _windowReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            int id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _id);
            _wnd.Invoke(new RegisterHotKeyDelegate(RegisterHotKeyInternal), _hwnd, id, (uint)KeyModifiers.None, (uint)key);
            return id;
        }

        public static void UnregisterHotKey(int id)
        {
            _wnd.Invoke(new UnRegisterHotKeyDelegate(UnRegisterHotKeyInternal), _hwnd, id);
        }

        delegate void RegisterHotKeyDelegate(IntPtr hwnd, int id, uint modifiers, uint key);
        delegate void UnRegisterHotKeyDelegate(IntPtr hwnd, int id);

        private static void RegisterHotKeyInternal(IntPtr hwnd, int id, uint modifiers, uint key)
        {
            RegisterHotKey(hwnd, id, modifiers, key);
        }

        private static void UnRegisterHotKeyInternal(IntPtr hwnd, int id)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(_hwnd, id);
        }

        private static void OnHotKeyPressed(HotKeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyListener.HotKeyPressed != null)
            {
                KeyListener.HotKeyPressed(null, e);
            }
        }

        private static volatile MessageWindow _wnd;
        private static volatile IntPtr _hwnd;
        private static ManualResetEvent _windowReadyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static KeyListener()
        {
            Thread messageLoop = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                Application.Run(new MessageWindow());
            });
            messageLoop.Name = "MessageLoopThread";
            messageLoop.IsBackground = true;
            messageLoop.Start();
        }

        private class MessageWindow : Form
        {
            public MessageWindow()
            {
                _wnd = this;
                _hwnd = this.Handle;
                _windowReadyEvent.Set();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    HotKeyEventArgs e = new HotKeyEventArgs(m.LParam);
                    KeyListener.OnHotKeyPressed(e);
                }

                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }

            protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
            {
                // Ensure the window never becomes visible
                base.SetVisibleCore(false);
            }

            private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        }

        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private static int _id = 0;
    }


    public class HotKeyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly Keys Key;
        public readonly KeyModifiers Modifiers;

        public HotKeyEventArgs(Keys key, KeyModifiers modifiers)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Modifiers = modifiers;
        }

        public HotKeyEventArgs(IntPtr hotKeyParam)
        {
            uint param = (uint)hotKeyParam.ToInt64();
            Key = (Keys)((param & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
            Modifiers = (KeyModifiers)(param & 0x0000ffff);
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyModifiers
    {
        None = 0,
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        Windows = 8,
        NoRepeat = 0x4000
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**

Now, there's still a delay. It's way more elegant, but you still have the operating system fighting you. So what to do?

You have two options.

**a)** You implement a timing option and you simply repeat the action for as long as a key is down on the timer tick event. You can either copy the code or merge it with the hotkey approach that I've given you.

See here for details: [Removing the delay after KeyDown event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942437/removing-the-delay-after-keydown-event)

```
private bool _moveUp;
private bool _moveDown;
private bool _moveLeft;
private bool _moveRight;

// You can add the Timer in the Winforms Designer instead if you like;
// The Interval property can be configured there at the same time, along
// with the Tick event handler, simplifying the non-Designer code here.
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _movementTimer = new Timer { Interval = 100 };

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _movementTimer.Tick += movementTimer_Tick;
}

private void movementTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DoMovement();
}

private void _DoMovement()
{
    if (_moveLeft) Player.MoveLeft();
    if (_moveRight) Player.MoveRight();
    if (_moveUp) Player.MoveUp();
    if (_moveDown) Player.MoveDown();
}

// You could of course override the OnKeyDown() method instead,
// assuming the handler is in the Form subclass generating the
// the event.
public void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsRepeat)
    {
        // Ignore key repeats...let the timer handle that
        return;
    }

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys.Up:
        _moveUp = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Down:
        _moveDown = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Left:
        _moveLeft = true;
        break;
    case Keys.Right:
        _moveRight = true;
        break;
    }

    _DoMovement();
    _movementTimer.Start();
}

public void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys.Up:
        _moveUp = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Down:
        _moveDown = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Left:
        _moveLeft = false;
        break;
    case Keys.Right:
        _moveRight = false;
        break;
    }

    if (!(_moveUp || _moveDown || _moveLeft || _moveRight))
    {
        _movementTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

**b)** In your Main method, you get the delay setting, set the delay programmatically to the lowest setting, and on Application Exit, you set it back to its original setting.

See here for where to find it in the registry: https://superuser.com/questions/388160/keyboard-repeat-rate-repeat-delay-values-in-win7

And how to read/write to the registry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

*Note:* With this approach, there's still a small delay. It's small, but it's there. Good luck.

Comment: Complex, but worth it.