# How to raise an event when a specific key pressed?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to make Pong as a Windows Form Application program using C# and I'd like the player to be able to move the paddle using the up and down arrow keys. This is the problem: I don't know how to raise an event when those keys are pressed. Specifically, I want the event to be continuously called as long as the keys are pressed. I've read the `GetKeyStates` method is used to register specific key presses, but whenever I try to use it the compiler throws some errors.

I've wrote a small program which has the same issues as the Pong app. It contains the following method:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.Down) & KeyStates.Down > 0)
    {
        label1.Text = num++.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `.cs` file also has the `using System.Windows.Input` directive at the top.

The compiler says that `Keyboard`, `KeyStates` and `Key` don't exist in the current context.

Comment: If you must use WinForms for this, use the KeyDown and KeyUp events to change the state of your game, then read the state from within the loop. (i.e. Change `isDownKeyPressed` when the event fires, then in your loop do `if (isDownKeyPressed) { ... }`)

Comment: As noted in the previous comment, you can and should use `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events. You don't need to write code "to raise an event when a specific key [is] pressed". Those _are_ the events; they already exist. As far as how to react to them, you should have a loop processing game state; you'll track key state in the event handlers, and update game state in your loop according to the current key state. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29957353 for an example of how that might work. It's not exactly the same as pong, but it's close enough you should have no trouble adapting the idea.