# The calling thread must be STA error

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I wanted to create a simple "piano" application, where I can press button while UI is not blocked.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => keyboard());
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

public async void keyboard()
{  
    while(true)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
        {

            btn_A_firstDo.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = false));
            //Play some music here...
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            btn_A_firstDo.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = true));

        }
    }   
}
```

I've got an error that I couldn't figure out the solution for it:
**"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."**
I'm getting this error at this part of the code:

```
if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
```

I still didn't fully understand this error despite I searched on this.
My questions are as follow:

1. How can I solved This error? And what causes this?
2. I don't think I used the `await` correctly. 
   I want for example to press 2 keys in parallel without blocking the UI.
   How to fix that?
3. Is there some way to make my code more elegant?

**EDIT:**
I've figured out the code that works:
(Also working on subscribing to event `KeyDown` , example will be shown..)

```
 public async void keyboard(Key key)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
                this.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => {
                    btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = false;
                    // Play some music..
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                this.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => {
                    btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = true;
                }));
        });
    }
```

Subscribing to event `KeyDown`:

```
private void Piano_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true; 
        this.KeyDown += SubKeyDown; // Deligate this event.
    }

    // Subscribing to event.
    void SubKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                keyboard(Key.A);
                break;
            // Continue with the cases...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly an answer to *3*: you should be subscribing to events rather than running a loop to check whether a key has been pressed.

Comment: Or if there aren't any appropriate events in this case, use a `Timer`.

Comment: What about the main problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.How can I solved This error? And what causes this?

You are getting the exception in spite of having set the thread apartment state because, due to your use of `await`, the second time through your loop you are no longer executing in the thread you originally started. The continuation, and every continuation after that, is getting executed in a thread pool thread. Your original thread has exited by that point.

> 2.I don't think I used the await correctly. I want for example to press 2 keys in parallel without blocking the UI. How to fix that?

There's not enough context in your question to know what the answer to that might be. The code you show involving `await` appears to be responsible for disabling some `Button` object in the UI while you "play some music". That can be done easily if you were to write a method called by the UI thread that looks similar to those three statements. For example:

```
private async Task PlayMusicA()
{
    btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = false;
    //Play some music here...
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    btn_A_firstDo.Enabled = true;
}
```

You could call that in, for example, a `Click` event handler:

```
private async void btn_A_firstDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PlayMusicA();
}
```

> 3.Is there some way to make my code more elegant?

For handling key input, it would make more sense for your form to monitor key input and respond to key input events, instead of polling the keyboard as you seem to be trying to do here.

Again, your question is vague so it's not clear exactly what you need to do, but you might find [an answer I wrote previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942437/removing-the-delay-after-keydown-event/29957353#29957353) that discusses how to track whether a key is pressed or not (i.e. "up" or "down") so that some *continuous* behavior can be applied while the key is down.

If, on the other hand, you only care about the initial key-press, and don't need to know when the key is released, that other answer won't help and isn't needed. All you need is to handle key input in your form. Unfortunately, this is a fairly complicated topic, because there are lots of variations. A form can have children that also want key input, and so there are several different events and methods you can override to receive key input, each of which have subtly different behavior. To describe all that in a single Stack Overflow answer is really too broad.

Instead, you should take a look at what's available. In a very simple scenario, it might be sufficient to subscribe in your form class to the `KeyPress` event. If your form contains other controls that would normally receive key input, but you want to be able to respond to specific keys, you might want to use the `PreviewKeyDown` event (which is a little different from `KeyPress`…the `KeyPress` event reports character input, after a specific key has been translated by Windows, while `PreviewKeyDown` tells you which physical key on the keyboard was pressed). If your scenario is more complicated than something that would work with either of those, you might find yourself having to override one of the `Process...` key methods in the form.

Again, there's just not enough information in your question to know for sure what would work best for you. You should use the advice above to try to make something work, and then if you still need help, spend some time to make a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain *precisely* what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explaination!!
I've wrote code that works, if you want, you can check it.
(I edited my question)
Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I posted the above without double-checking the code, and I'd forgotten to remove the unneeded `BeginInvoke()` calls. See edit. Your `keyboard()` method should look more like that; no `Task.Run()`, no anonymous method, and no `BeginInvoke()`. Just set the button state, play the music, use `Task.Delay()` to wait whatever period you want, and then set the button state again. It's not clear from your question how you're playing the music; if that would block the thread, you can use `await Task.Run(() => ...)` for that, and that part only.