# How to remove delay when pressing a key?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a rectangle on the screen and make it move, but when I press a key it gives delay and then walks.

Let's imagine I want to go forward with the "W" key, then suddenly I want to turn to the left by pressing the "A" key, when I press the "A" key, it will give me a delay. This is what happens with the rectangle form below

[image]

I tried putting the timer as a single solution, but I could not.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        r = new Rectangle(new Point(4, 4), new Size(8, 8));
    }

    private Rectangle r;
    private Keys keys;

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (keys)
        {
            case Keys.W:
                r.Y -= 5;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                r.Y += 5;
                break;
            case Keys.D:
                r.X += 5;
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                r.X -= 5;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), r);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        keys = e.KeyCode;            
    }
```

I want to move the rectangle without delay by pressing any key

Comment: Don't use a Timer, then. Set the new location and `Invalidate()` directly. Do you have problems with repeated key presses?

Comment: But if I take out the Timer it will be worse because the delay when pressing the key will be more time consuming.

Comment: *I want to move the rectangle without delay by pressing any key*. Do you want a delay or not? If you don't use a Timer = No delay, with a Timer = Delay needed. What is it? If you mean: I have a delay because I need to press and release the keys, override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey). You can then keep a key pressed to move your shape.

Comment: I do not want delays, I want to move the rectangle freely by the form

Comment: The actions will be by pressing a key on the keyboard. When I make a transition from one key to another it gives a delay, and I do not want that, do you understand? I want to kill this delay.

Comment: So you want to avoid the delay when key pressed and event occurs. To avoid that you created a timer, which gets activated whenever key down event happens. That's once or same thing.

Comment: What is the interval set to on the timer?

Comment: @Arpit Gupta That's right, when I use the above code, when I move from one key to another, it gives a delay that I did not want

Comment: @ArpitGupta Interval = 1

Comment: Please check this link. It may be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942437/removing-the-delay-after-keydown-event

Comment: Arpit Gupta Wooow it worked fine with this link.

Comment: Can declare as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Just call the timer handler immediately when you enable the timer.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    Timer1_Tick(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your answer to my problem in several ways, but it continues to give delay to the change of keys